# Two working forms on one page

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I want two forms on my page that use the same script. The first one is sent correctly, but the second is not. I'm very beginner in PHP and I have no idea how to do it. I am trying to solve this, unfortunately without results. I'm using the phpmailer.

First form:

```
<div id="form-main">
   <form class="montform" id="reused_form" enctype=&quot;multipart/form-data&quot;>
      <p class="company">
         <input name="company" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Nazwa firmy" id="company"/>
      </p>
      <p class="name">
         <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" required placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko" id="name"/>
      </p>
      <p class="phone">
         <input name="phone" type="tel" required class="feedback-input" id="phone" placeholder="Telefon"/>
      </p>
      <p class="email">
         <input name="email" type="email" required class="feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Adres e-mail"/>
      </p>
      <p class="text">
         <textarea name="message" class="feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Opis zamówienia"></textarea>
      </p>
      <button type="submit" class="button-blue">Send</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Second form:

```
<div id="second-form">
   <form class="montform" id="reused_form" enctype=&quot;multipart/form-data&quot;>
   <p class="name">
      <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" required placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko" id="name"/>
   </p>
   <p class="phone">
      <input name="phone" type="tel" required class="feedback-input" id="phone" placeholder="Telefon"/>
   </p>
   <button type="submit" class="button-blue">Send</button>
</form>
```

handler.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )
*/
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;

$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email','phone','company'])->areRequired()- 
>maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);

$pp->attachFiles(['image']);

$pp->sendEmailTo('sadowm1990@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Comment: Well I would suggest checking which form got submitted before attempting to validate fields that may not exists in the form that was submitted

Comment: _Small Note:_ `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` is irrelevant

Comment: Start by giving the Buttons a `name=` attribute and make each on a different name. Then you can check which button caused the submit

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a separate name attribute to the buttons. The first form is sent, and the second one leaves the link in the browser "http://localhost:3000/?name=Maciej+Sadowski&phone=46464664&leaveNumber=" and does not send.

Answer (score 0):

First: I am pretty sure both of your forms are sent/submitted without any problems. Your second form misses the div closing tag **`</div>`** but that shouldn't make such problems.

By "**the first one is sent correctly, but the second is not.**" I assume you mean that you are not getting any email on the selected address when using the second form. If that is the case then:

I am not sure how your **validator** functions but it looks like that your problem is **the validation process**.

Why? : In your php code you are validating **name, email, phone, company, message** but only your first form have chance to satisfy those because it has those fields. Your second form doesn't have all those fields which have to be validated, so, your validation is going to fail. As consequence you are not going to receive any email (if the validator functions in that way).

In order to make your second form to function on this php code you have either to:
1. differentiate those two forms in your php code and apply the correct validation on them or
2. add missing fields to your second form (you can still make them hidden using html/css, but you need to set their default values and submit them altogether, I don't recommend doing this).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But how to make 'differentiate those two forms in your php code and apply the correct validation on them' ?

Comment: One simple approach would be to create hidden fields (with the same name) inside your forms and set them different default values (0 and 1, for example). Once you submit such a form you can check in your php code which value did you get and validate correspondingly.

Comment: I added the remaining fields to the second form and added the value to them, but the form still does not send.